# Sorting Numbers in O(N)?

Tags: reductions, sorting

Why is sorting numbers Omega(nlogn)? I'm thinking of an reduction algorithm where:

For all the numbers x_i, we create a point (x_i, 0) on  a 2d graph.

Fit a line directly to the right  starting from the leftmost point.

Sorted numbers are the order in which we encounter the points.

Would this not be an O(n) number sorting algorithm?

Comment: I suggest you to try to implement the algorithm and see where you encounter the problem. You'll notice that finding "the order in which we encounter the points" is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493308/why-is-it-impossible-to-find-a-specified-value-in-a-sorted-array-faster-than-ol

Comment: Why a 2D graph, if all ordinates are $0$ ??

Comment: Why a 2D graph, if all ordinates are $0$ ? And what it the use of *fitting* a line when you know that line already ?? And what would be the cost of that fitting ???

Comment: Notice that knowing a line that contains all points does not give you any clue about their order.

Comment: @YvesDaoust answer detected

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to analyse your algorithm; it's very instructive for you to discover if it will work or not. But let's talk about the computational complexity of sorting.

Let's assume for a moment that you have $n$ items, all of which are distinct.

There are $n!$ possible ways to put these in order. You can think of sorting as discovering which of these permutations is the correct one. If you think about it, this is equivalent to determining an integer between $1$ and $n!$ (or, equivalently, between $0$ and $n!-1$).

How much information do you need to do that?

Well, given $k$ bits of information, you can distinguish at most $2^k$ possible things. Or, alternatively, you can represent a number between $1$ and $2^k$ or between $0$ and $2^k-1$.

So it follows that to sort these $n$ items, you need $\log_2 n!$ bits of information.

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\log_2 n! = n \log_2 n - n \log_2 e + O(\log_2 n) = \Omega(n \log n)$$

Therefore, you need $\Omega(n \log n)$ bits of information to sort $n$ items.

If all you have to test items is a "less than" comparison operator, then this returns one bit of information every time you call it, so you must perform $\Omega(n \log n)$ comparisons. You cannot get around this, because if you perform any fewer comparisons, you do not have enough information to distinguish between all possible permutations of the input.

This does not, however, mean that, in general, sorting requires $O(n \log n)$ time. We can do better than this if we modify our assumptions.

For example, what if not all of the $n$ items were distinct? If they were all the same, you can test this in $O(n)$ time, and then sorting is a $O(1)$ no-op.

In general, sorting $n$ items which are not necessarily distinct requires $O(nH)$ comparisons, where $H$ is the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the keys.

Another assumption we could change is the one that we only have a test/query operation that returns one bit of information. If we had one that returned $O(\log n)$ bits of information, we might be able to sort in $O(n)$ time. And, indeed, we can do this using an algorithm such as [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) under some reasonable assumptions (e.g. that you are sorting integers in the range $[1,n^c]$ for some constant $c$).

Just as an aside, because I love this paper, I have to mention this again. An algorithm is known that stably sorts $n$ integers in the range $[1,n^c]$, in $O(n)$ time, using $O(1)$ extra space. This means that, from a theoretical perspective, [in-place integer sorting is a solved problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.4107).

Your language's standard library probably only supplies a comparison-based sort. The reason why is not because it's the fastest algorithm available, but because it has the most convenient user interface. "Library sort" algorithms need to work with user-defined types, and requiring the user to only write a "less than" or "less than or equal to" operator makes it much easier to use.

Comment: This discussion has little to do with the question, as it assumes a comparison-only model. The OP imagines some kind of geometric model that is more powerful (though it does not map to an accepted computer model such as a RAM). In fact the OP's model sorts *by magic* in zero time, and the $O(n)$ time is required to draw the points and enumerate them in sorted ordeR.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The first question asked was "Why is sorting numbers Omega(nlogn)?"

Comment: The bound $\Omega(n\log(n))$ is known to hold for comparison-based sorting, but could very well hold for other sorting methods (in some way it does for radix-sort, as the key length must depend on $n$). And again the OP suggests an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in terms of a putative geometric computer, that implements an implicit order axiom, and is operated by an observer. What you are missing is that the observer has a *synoptic* view on that data, with an apparent $O(1)$ complexity, and is similar to parallel computing. This is not how a sequential computer works.

---

Now imagine a mechanical computer holding a paper strip such that its length is sufficient to represent the whole range of input values. It can move the strip at constant speed to any location and punch a hole. It can also detect the holes and return their position.

Assuming that the total travel time is proportional to $n$ [which is a questionable hypothesis], this computer will sort as follows:

1. move to every position in turn and punch a hole;
2. return to the leftmost point;
3. detect all holes from left to right.

In the worst case, the first operation will take time $O(n^2)$ and the other two, time $O(n)$. The sorting per se takes no time, it is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort *some* arrays in O(n). One case is an array of n elements, created by starting with a sorted array of n elements, and modifying O (n / ln n) of those elements. An obvious case is an array that is already sorted, or sorted in reverse order, or the concatenation of two arrays that are each sorted or sorted in reverse order.

These cases happen quite often. For example, you might have a list of employees sorted by last name, and over a month a few of those change their last name, or have typos corrected. As long as the number of changed entries is O (n / ln n), you can sort the array in O (n).